# I can't change langauge with my Logitech Bluetooth keyboard using custom keyboard app

Tags: iphone, keyboard, bluetooth, ios

When I use a custom keyboard app (like gboard), my Bluetooth keyboard can't change its language (from English to other)

But when I use Apple's default keyboard (after deleting the custom keyboard option), my Bluetooth keyboard can change language very well.

Why does it work with Apple's default keyboard? Is there any way to change language with a Bluetooth keyboard too?

---

Specs: iPhone - iOS 9.3.4

Comment: @klanomath My mistake. It's 9.3.4

Comment: It's iPhone, I didn't test iPad

Answer (score 1):

Only Apple keyboards let you use different hardware layouts in iOS.  No 3rd party keyboards allow for that feature yet as far as I know.